# Can anyone explain the rule that explains why Россия declines to России in the prepositional?

Tags: падежи

I'm following Penguin's Russian Course and it doesn't make it clear.

It says words ending with и, а , о the last letter is substituted by e and that in words ending with a consonant we add e.

It also gives the rule to words ending with ь (substituted by e if masculine or и if feminine), but what about the other endings, like я?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/why-it-is-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b8-but-not-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8e

Answer (score 3):

If a word ends in -ия, in the prepositional the ending is -ии. This is also applied to proper names on -ия. If the word's ending is -я, then it is usually replaced by the ending -е

Comment: Here are some more examples of words ending with -ия and their prepositional singular form: http://russian.morpheem.com/form/-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F@prep?word=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 3):

I've often presented it like this: nouns in -ий, -ия, and -ие all have -ии in the prepositional: кафетерий > в кафетерии, Россия > в России, здание > в здании. So this group is a little different from other nouns in the prepositional singular.

Answer (score 1):

> what about the other endings, like я?

We have several types of declension of nouns and some nouns are not declined.
Nouns which end with -я belong to the first declension.
They include feminine gender nouns like земля, статья, экскурсия, masculine gender nouns (дядя, Ваня), common gender nouns (соня)

They have the following forms*:

> земля, земли, земле,землю, землёй (землёю), земле
>
> семья, семьи, семье, семью, семьёй (семьёю), семье.

**Forms shown above for the words земля (earth) and семья (family) are singular case declensions of the following (and in this order):*

> *nominative - genitive - dative - accusative - instrumental - prepositional*

But nouns ending with *-ия* have *-ии* in the dative and prepositional :

> России, Марии, Софии, экскурсии.

Answer (score 1):

We have different types of declensions. School course says that we have 3 types. However, the things are more complicated. [Andrey Zaliznyak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Zaliznyak) had developed his own classification for Russian declensions. For example, Russian Wiktionary uses a slightly modified version of his classification. So, according to this classification, the word `Россия` is a type 7a declension. And that said it is declined accordingly.

Further sources:

- [А. А. Зализняк. Грамматический словарь русского языка.](https://gramdict.ru/declension/symbols)
- [Russian Wiktionary - Использование словаря Зализняка.](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Can you add a link to this classification?

Comment: 4 years later, but I did that :D