# Why it is "об Англии", but not "об Англиe"?

Tags: падежи

"Об" is followed by prepositional case, and according [to this](http://www.russianlessons.net/grammar/nouns_prepositional.php) page, feminine nouns ending with "я" in prepositional should end with "е".

That said, it shouldn't be "об Англии" but rather "об Англие". What do I miss?

Comment: please clarify why in you opinion it should end with "и". Providing a link is not enough, question supposed to be self-sufficient to a certain level.

Comment: @shabunc , I said it shouldn't end with "и", because in prepositional case, it says Replace “я” with “е” However or this word, it is not following up the rules. I sent the link as the list of rules, and none of the rules clarifies its structure. So I am looking for why?

Comment: I closed your question because it was not clear enough, I've edited it to give an idea of what I meant so that next time it would be clearer to you. Once again, question supposed to be self-sufficient, any link can get stale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource you were referring to oversimplified things too much. Words ending with "ь", "ия", "ие", "ий" end with "и" in prepositional, so "о речи", "о Франции", "о знамении" and "об аграрии".

I recommend you to refer to wiktionary whenever you have doubts - Russian section always comes with declensions, with ["Англия"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F) being no exception to that rule.